# Delete Record with PHP Confirm Prompt

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I am trying to present the user with a confirm yes/no prompt before deleting an author from a Mysql Database. When a user hits Delete in the authors.html.php, the controller includes a confirm.php.  The confirm.php  prompts the user for a yes or no to confirm.  If the yes button is clicked, the confirm.php is meant to pass the id back to the controller which then checks if the action isset, and if yes, delete the author based on the id.

Unfortunately the author does not get deleted, so the issue is with the the inclusion of the confirm prompt. Without the confirm include, the script works perfectly well, but I want to figure out what is going wrong and it's all too easy to use Javascript.

Any help appreciated.

My controller: index.php

```
//inlcude the data connection.
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/authors/includes/db.inc.php';

try
{
  $result = $pdo->query('SELECT id, name FROM author'); //Rows of a result set returned by fetch are represented as associative arrays,
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
  $error = 'Error fetching authors from the database!';
  include 'error.html.php';
  exit();
}

foreach ($result as $row)
{
  $authors[] = array('id' => $row['id'], 'name' => $row['name']);
}

include 'authors.html.php';


if(isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'Delete') {

include "confirm.php";

  if(isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'Yes') {

    try {
        $sql = 'DELETE FROM author WHERE id = :id';
        $s = $pdo -> prepare($sql);
        $s->bindValue(':id', $_POST['id']);
        $s->execute();
    }

    catch (PDOException $e) {
        $error = "Error deleting author.";
        include 'error.html.php';
        exit();
    }

    header('Location: .');
    exit();

  }// if yes

} // end if isset delete
```

The authors.html.php then displays a list of authors:

```
<?php foreach ($authors as $author): ?><!-- loop through the list of authors pulled from the database by the controller -->
    <li>
      <form action="" method="post">
        <div>
          <?php htmlout($author['name']); ?> <!--display a list of authors and an edit and delete button-->
          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php
              echo $author['id']; ?>">
          <input type="submit" name="action" value="Edit">
          <input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete">
        </div>
      </form>
    </li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

confirm.php ......

```
<form action="" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $author['id']; ?>">
 <input type="submit" name="action" value="Yes">
 <!--input type="submit" name="action" value="No"-->
</form>
```

Comment: your confirm form is wrong. it should be `$_POST['id']`, so you capture the ID of the author that was selected for deletion, **NOT** `$author['id']`, which is the last author that was output in the list of authors.

Comment: Hm, I don't really understand how this is meant to work... You are aware that you can only include such a confirmation script in a full reload of the page shown in the browser by means of php? That sounds very unintuitive. Wouldn't it make more sense to implement the confirmation step based on a pure client side logic (javascript) or an ajax call (also based on javascript) if the server has to be consulted in between the steps?

Comment: Mark B, when change the value of the hidden field to $_POST['id'], it still doesn't work.

Comment: arkascha, yes I made it clear in my post that JS or Ajax would resolve the problem, but I still want to figure out what's gone wrong from a purely learning point of view.  I already see that you get penalised for asking questions and the desire to learn - can't win

Comment: Have you tried this: `$sql='DELETE FROM author WHERE id ='.$_POST[id]` OR `$sql="DELETE FROM author WHERE id = $_POST[id]"`. I think you meant `$_POST[id]` and not `id` . If you use variable names in a single quote in php, they wouldn't be interpreted as variables. So I have used `.` operator to concatenate the variable with the string. Other option could be using double quotes which interprets the variables (not sure if double quotes work when passed as query). Just a suggestion. Not sure though. "Someone correct me if I am wrong. Please!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking in terms of PHP, Instead of trying to process everything in a single `action` file (*controller in MVC*), what you should be doing is.. Make the second form to post to a different controller.

Say you have a form/table that contains the button/form that deletes the author. Let that form/button call a file named as `confirm.php` with the `id` of that author passed.

Inside the confirm page you render the confirm form with the `yes`/`no` input. And then this `confirm.php` will post to a `delete.php` which will check if the confirmation value is set inside the `$_GET`/`$_POST` and proceed as such.

*Also on a side note I recommend that you learn some very basic javascript and use the `confirm()` function.*

*Also on a side side note, I strongly recommend that you learn some validation, sanitization, escaping, and about sessions.*

Comment: Hi Mohd, posting to a separate delete.php has solved the problem.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I cant put comment in your Post, just a answer (I dont have required reputation).

So, your logic is wrong, see:

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'Delete') {

include "confirm.php";

  if(isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'Yes') {
```

When the `$_POST['action'] == 'Yes'` the script will not pass to the:

```
try {
        $sql = 'DELETE FROM author WHERE id = :id';
        $s = $pdo -> prepare($sql);
        $s->bindValue(':id', $_POST['id']);
        $s->execute();
    }
```

Because the `$_POST['action']` is not **'Delete'** anymore.

I think the condition `if(isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'Yes')` must be outside the `if(isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'Delete')`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Lucas, but when you change the name and value to yes in the confirm page, and check if(isset($_POST['yes'])) in the controller, therefore avoiding conflict, it still doesn't work.

Comment: If the YES condition remains within the DELETE, you may have to place the `<input type="hidden" name="action" value="Delete">` also in the form of confirm.php. Because, anyway, you missed the **action == Delete** (sorry for my english)

Comment: Lucas your suggestions have been very helpful.  Thank you for you help